# Sum up columns and divide them by adjacent cell

Tags: r

I have the following table:

| Date | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/10/2021 | 20 | 25 | 25 | 26 | 26 | 25 | 31 |
| 08/10/2021 | 26 | 25 | 25 | 26 | 25 | 31 |  |
| 09/10/2021 | 29 | 29 | 25 | 26 | 39 |  |  |
| 10/10/2021 | 20 | 29 | 25 | 31 |  |  |  |
| 11/10/2021 | 20 | 30 | 30 |  |  |  |  |
| 12/10/2021 | 30 | 30 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1/10/2022 | 39 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

```
## example data d:
d <- 
structure(list(Date = c("07.10.2021", "08.10.2021", "09.10.2021", 
"10.10.2021", "11.10.2021", "12.10.2021", "01.10.2022"), X1 = c(20L, 
26L, 29L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 39L), X2 = c(25L, 25L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 
30L, NA), X3 = c(25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 30L, NA, NA), X4 = c(26L, 
26L, 26L, 31L, NA, NA, NA), X5 = c(26L, 25L, 39L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), X6 = c(25L, 31L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X7 = c(31L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 7L))
```

I'm trying to add up the columns, but only up to the column that has an adjacent cell. I then am trying to divide each sum by the previous sum. For example, column 1 and 2 would add down to 12/10/2021 and then column 2 would be divided by column 1. The output would be the table plus a row with the total values under each of the columns, as shown below:

| Date | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/10/2021 | 20 | 25 | 25 | 26 | 26 | 25 | 31 |
| 08/10/2021 | 26 | 25 | 25 | 26 | 25 | 31 |  |
| 09/10/2021 | 29 | 29 | 25 | 26 | 39 |  |  |
| 10/10/2021 | 20 | 29 | 25 | 31 |  |  |  |
| 11/10/2021 | 20 | 30 | 30 |  |  |  |  |
| 12/10/2021 | 30 | 30 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1/10/2022 | 39 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| TOTAL | 1 | 1.10 | .94 | 1.09 | 1.15 | 1.09 | 1.24 |

I tried:

```
f <- function(.x, .y) {
  keep_rows <- cumsum(is.na(.y)) == 0
  sum(.x[keep_rows])
}
```

but that didn't work

Comment: Hard to understand what exactly you're asking for. Better that you provide an example data frame of your expected output.

Comment: Sorry, I put the desired output under "total" in the second table.

Comment: Please provide reproducible data, i.e. append the information of `dput(your_data)` to your question.

Comment: Shouldn't the results for columns 2 and 6 read 1.16 and 1.10, following your recipe and rounding?

Comment: Yes, that was a miscalculation. I apologize for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one approach:

```
(d[,8:3] |> apply(2, cumsum)/
 d[,7:2] |> apply(2, cumsum)
) |>
  diag() |>
  rev() |>
  setNames(nm = names(d)[-c(1:2)])
```

result:

```
##       X2       X3       X4       X5       X6       X7 
## 1.158621 0.942029 1.090000 1.153846 1.098039 1.240000
```

where `d` is your dataframe:

```
d <- 
structure(list(Date = c("07.10.2021", "08.10.2021", "09.10.2021", 
"10.10.2021", "11.10.2021", "12.10.2021", "01.10.2022"), X1 = c(20L, 
26L, 29L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 39L), X2 = c(25L, 25L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 
30L, NA), X3 = c(25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 30L, NA, NA), X4 = c(26L, 
26L, 26L, 31L, NA, NA, NA), X5 = c(26L, 25L, 39L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), X6 = c(25L, 31L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X7 = c(31L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 7L))
```